# Selenium- Current window closes and new opens in a browser window

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to automate an app in which when I go to a screen and click a button, it closes the current window, and opens new one, which closes again and new one opens. This happens 4 times and then finally I am at the window where the app to be tested it. Selenium WD is not able to recognize the final window when it is opened. Any one has faced this issue in the past?

Comment: Presumably it works OK when you follow the process manually? Can you show us the relevant parts of your code? Otherwise we are just guessing...

Comment: Yes, it work fine when I do it manually. Automation team in the past used Rational Funtional Tester and was able to get this done. We are trying Selenium for the time with this app. I am sorry, I can't give an example to you for this out on the web since its an internal app. Closing and opening happens because of redirects in the url from the launch page to final app. I have tried using switchTo and getWindowHandler methods from WD and we had no luck.

Comment: If you can't give the actual code, can you please specify what browser and version and selenium code(use variables to avoid specifics) for steps 1, 2, 3, 4 for the windows that are successful and then step 5 that isn't successful?  Also is there anything different about the 5th window that isn't like the others?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but a possible solution would be to tell Selenium to focus on the new open window when it has stopped changing 4 times.

So you wait for the time for your application to open/close all these windows and at the end you do :

```
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
```

This way Selenium should focus on the last open window